# Move a Service-Dependent Component to a Shared Module

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a component called `CarDetailsComponent` which makes use of a `CarApiService`, both of which are in `CarModule`. Now I want to move that component out to a `SharedModule`. As multiple modules also require that same component. I cannot share the whole `CarModule` as it already imports the other modules (e.g:, `CustomerModule`, `ShopModule`) into it.

Moving `CarDetailsComponent` to `SharedModule` is not a problem, but how do I now handle the dependent service (`CarApiService`) since it is also used by the component as well as other components in the `CarModule`.

I tried to use providers (`useClass` and the lot) to replace the service with another service of the module it is being used in. However, all I end up doing is copy-pasting the same functions into the services of other modules.

I did think about moving the `CarApiService` into the `SharedModule` as well, but it really belongs in `CarModule` (as most of the components here use it, and only `CarDetailsComponent` makes use of the service).

What is a better approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `CarApiService` need to be in a module (each module has its own singleton of that service), or does the whole app use the same instance?

If its the latter, you can remove `CarpApiService` from all your modules, and change your `@Injctor` decorator to this:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

You can then import it in any constructor without having it added to that components module.

See the Angular docs for more info: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: This approach works, thanks! One question: does this mean that the service class will only be imported when required (is it tree-shakeable)?

Comment: It should, depending on how you call it. check this from angular docs https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#tree-shakable-providers

Answer (score 1):

What about making a CarDetailModule where you declare and export the CarDetailsComponent
and import it where you need it?